# saber si es posible pasar un valor string como si fuera el nombre de una lista

Tags: c#

Quisiera saber si es posible pasar un valor string como si fuera el nombre de una lista.
Como este ejemplo:

```
List<Datos> List1 = new List<Datos>();  
string NomLista = "List1";
VerDatoLista(NomLista);
public void VerDatoLista(List<Datos> listaIn)
{
MessageBox.Show((listaIn[0] as Datos).DDescripcion);
}
```

Comment: Solo tengo dos preguntas relacionadas a lo que deseas relizar: ¿Por qué y para qué?

Comment: la función VerDatosLista espera un parámetro de entrada de tipo List y quieres pasarle un string. No se puede hacer de manera directa. Podrías crear un diccionario donde la clave sea el string y el valor un List.

Comment: Seguramente no es la manera mas adecuada, pero lo que necesito es crear 50 listas : List1,List2,List3..... hasta 50  y si se pudiera Asignar una variable como nombre de una lista me ahorraria mucho trabajo. Además de luego acceder a ellas.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear un diccionarios de listas

```
Dictionary<string, List<Datos>> listas = new Dictionary<string, List<Datos>>();

//Nueva lista
listas.Add("nombre_lista", new List<Datos>());

//agregar dato a una lista
listas["nombre_lista"].Add(new Datos());

//Exista la lista de nombre "lista1" ??
if(listas.ContainsKey("lista1"))
{
    //si
}
else {
    //no
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, he creado diccionarios de listas y funciona muy bien. Gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: @javifdz Que bueno te sirvió la ayuda. No te olvides de marcar la respuesta como aceptada

Comment: Hola @Yussef cuando instancias tu diccionario de listas pones <string, string, List<Datos>>, no debería ser <string, List<Datos>>?

Comment: @Japv Tienes toda la razón!!